# How do i identify the current active position of UITableView Leading & Trailing Swipe Actions (ios 11)?

Tags: ios, swift

With iOS 11, Apple introduced two new methods handling Swipe-Actions in UITableView on leading and trailing edge of the row (These methods were introduced as a part of UITableViewDelegate):

> tableView(*:leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)
>   tableView(*:trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)

But, there is no way to identify the current active Swipe-Action.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4:**
Luckily I was able to help myself and would like to share with you my solution:

```
extension UITableView {

    enum SwipeActionPosition {
        case unknown, leading, trailing
    }

    var activeSwipeActionPosition:SwipeActionPosition {

        var position = SwipeActionPosition.unknown

        for view in subviews {

            if String(describing: type(of:view) ) == "UISwipeActionPullView" {
                if view.frame.origin.x > 0.0 && view.frame.origin.x < self.frame.width {
                    position = .trailing
                } else if view.frame.origin.x == 0.0 {
                    position = .leading
                }

                break
            }
        }

        return position
    }
}
```

Example:

```
if self.tableView.activeSwipeActionPosition == .leading {
    //active leading swipe action
} else if self.tableView.activeSwipeActionPosition == .trailing {
    //active trailing swipe action
} else {
   //unknown
}
```

Comment: When user swipes from left `tableView(:leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)` will called and when user swipes from right `tableView(:trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt:)` will called. So for different swipe direction different delegate will call. now what you wanted to identify?

Comment: @dahiya_boy: In my case, the swipe gesture to close the new trailing swipe action seems not well implemented (only tapping or swiping on partially areas on cell are working to close the action). So I came to the solution to configure an invisible  leading swipe action as well to have full swipe gesture support in both directions, but only on the active trailing swipe action. To stop showing the leading swipe action (not needed in my case) , i needed a way to identify the current active action.